# How to filter by date in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a basic table with simple data. I need to filter data by date, for example, I want to see only items with dates between `03/03/2016` and `03/04/2016`.

[image: My table with formula:]

This query looks like this:

```
select A, B WHERE A >= 42432 AND A <= 42463
```

If I change date in cells `B1` and `C1`, numbers (`42432` and `42463`) are changing as well. But items are not being filtered.

So what should I do?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Are you looking to sort by date or filter data between dates? The query string in E4 is trying to query column A for dates but those are in column B. Perhaps there is a mixup in setting up the demo sheet.

Comment: I mean fliter data between dates. Now I've edited my query, but it doesn't work. Here's a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AT3PT5emwCOoACEzRpMRjGxqihDNp9Y9g_fY9qK8h_I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering dates with the `query()` function requires special syntax: `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`.

```
=query(A:B,"select A, B WHERE B >= date '2016-02-03' AND B <= date '2016-04-03'")
```

If you need to reference a cell with dates in them, the cells will have dates as numbers. You'll need to convert the format to `yyyy-mm-dd` like so:

```
=query(A:B,"select A, B WHERE B >= date '"&text(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B <= date '"&text(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

[Ref docs here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals).

Answer (score 5):

you can filter also with `FILTER` like:

```
=FILTER(A4:B, B4:B >= B1, B4:B <= C1)
```

[image: 0]